# How to change tier of blobs in a batch using batch_set_standard_blob_tier part of BlockBlobService?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.blockblobservice?view=azure-python#batch-set-standard-blob-tier-batch-set-blob-tier-sub-requests--timeout-none-) for the batch_set_standard_blob_tier function part of BlockBlobService in azure python SDK is not clear. 
What exactly should be passed in the parameter?
An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly should be passed in the parameter?

Input to this method is a list of [`BatchSetBlobTierSubRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.models.batchsetblobtiersubrequest?view=azure-python) object.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a direct answer to your question, but in the [v12 actually in preview](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0b4/), I believe the usage is far more obvious:

https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-python/ref/azure.storage.blob.html#azure.storage.blob.ContainerClient.set_standard_blob_tier_blobs

[image]

Example of code:

```
    tiers = [StandardBlobTier.Archive, StandardBlobTier.Cool, StandardBlobTier.Hot]

    for tier in tiers:
        blob = container.get_blob_client('blob1')
        data = b'hello world'
        blob.upload_blob(data)
        container.get_blob_client('blob2').upload_blob(data)
        container.get_blob_client('blob3').upload_blob(data)

        blob_ref = blob.get_blob_properties()
        assert blob_ref.blob_tier is not None
        assert blob_ref.blob_tier_inferred
        assert blob_ref.blob_tier_change_time is None

        parts = container.set_standard_blob_tier_blobs(
            tier,
            'blob1',
            'blob2',
            'blob3',
        )

        parts = list(parts)
        assert len(parts) == 3

        assert parts[0].status_code in [200, 202]
        assert parts[1].status_code in [200, 202]
        assert parts[2].status_code in [200, 202]

        blob_ref2 = blob.get_blob_properties()
        assert tier == blob_ref2.blob_tier
        assert not blob_ref2.blob_tier_inferred
        assert blob_ref2.blob_tier_change_time is not None
```

The new Storage SDK is planned to be GA stable release in November 2019, so it's really close and might worth a try.

Note that you can always open questions about code and documentation, whatever versions of SDK, in Github:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

Even if you can't use the preview right now, feedback on the new API would be appreciated :)

(Disclosure: I work at MS in the SDK team)